# Cómo distribuir una app construida en Python con TKINTER?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

soy usuario de MACOs, y querría saber si se puede hacer una aplicación de escritorio con python, me explico, que se vea como una aplicacion sin tener que ejecutarlo desde el ide, esta hecho con tkinter, y si es posible, si se puede pasar la aplicacion a alguien y que pueda ejecutarla aunque no tenga python instalado, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Sí. Uno normalmente debe entregar un ejecutable que contenga todo lo necesario para la ejecución del programa por sí solo.

Para Windows sería [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) o [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). Para OSx es [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Normalmente este proceso revisa todos los módulos requeridos y los incluye en el compilado.

Ejemplo de PyInstaller para generar un ejecutable (tomado del tutorial):

```
C:\Tutorial>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
creating python loader for extension 'zlib'
creating python loader for extension 'unicodedata'
creating python loader for extension 'bz2'
*** finding dlls needed ***
*** create binaries ***
*** byte compile python files ***
byte-compiling C:\Tutorial\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\bz2.py to bz2.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Tutorial\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\unicodedata.py to unicodedata.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Tutorial\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp\zlib.py to zlib.pyc
skipping byte-compilation of c:\Python24\lib\StringIO.py to StringIO.pyc

[skipping many lines for brevity]

skipping byte-compilation of c:\Python24\lib\warnings.py to warnings.pyc
*** copy extensions ***
*** copy dlls ***
copying c:\Python24\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run.exe -> C:\Tutorial\dist\hello.exe

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll

C:\Tutorial>
```

En el cliente que ejecute el archivo generado suele haber algunos requerimientos menores (la librería del runtime de Visual C, el DLL).

Para py2app (generar un ejecutable para OSx), uno crea un setup.py que le dice a la herramienta todo lo que debe tener en cuenta y luego corre el python setup.py py2app. Revisa la documentación relacionada.